# Find best match in tree given a combination of multiple keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a structure / tree that looks similar to this.

CostType is mandatory and can exist by itself, but it can have a parent ProfitType or Unit and other CostTypes as children.

There can only be duplicate Units. Other cannot appear multiple times in the structure.

```
| ID | name          | parent_id | ProfitType | CostType | Unit |
| -: | ------------- | --------: |
|  1 | Root          |    (NULL) | 
|  2 | 1             |         1 |       300  |          |      |
|  3 | 1-1           |         2 |            |      111 |      |
|  4 | 1-1-1         |         3 |            |          |    8 |
|  5 | 1-2           |         2 |            |      222 |      |
|  6 | 1-2-1         |         5 |            |      333 |      |
|  7 | 1-2-1-1       |         6 |            |          |    8 |
|  8 | 1-2-1-2       |         6 |            |          |    9 |


Parameters           |  should RETURN           |

(300,111,8)          | 4                        |
(null,111,8)         | 4                        |
(null,null,8)        | first match, 4           |
(null,222,8)         | best match, 5            |
(null,333,null)      | 6                        |
```

I am at a loss on how I could create a function that receives (ProfitType, CostType, Unit) and return the best matching ID from the structure.

Comment: So you want the function to return the ID of the deepest node that contains all of the specified arguments itself or in its parents? Your example shows CostType 333 as a child of CostType 222, is that a typo or is your data really that flexible, and if it is that flexible, is there a limit to how deep it can go?

Comment: Why is the best match for (null,222,8) node 5 (the desired unit is below) but the best match for (null,111,8) 4? Should the desired value for (null,222,8) be Node 7? If not, why does one pick the unit and the other the CostType when there is a direct root to leaf traversal including both CostType and Unit for both?

Comment: @RobertSheahan  The best I can figure -- ID 4 is an exact match for null,111,8 because 8 inherits CostType 111 from its parent ID 3.  I too am uncertain about why null,222,8 is ID 5; but I believe it's because ID 7 matches Unit but not CostType where ID 5 matches CostType and not Unit -- and that would presumably be because Units can have duplicates where the others cannot.

Comment: @RobertSheahan Units can have multiple appearances in the tree while CostTypes are unique. (null,222,8) does not return 7 because I only consider the immediate parent. Unit 8 is not an immediate parent of  CostType 222. ID 5 could also have different units as children to it that would not be 8.

Comment: That helps, but I'm still a bit fuzzy on the rules. What are valid parent child relations, that is, can a Profit Type be a direct parent of a Unit? Can a Unit be a parent of a Cost Type or Profit type? If I have a relationship of Profit->Cost_1->Cost_2->Unit does the Profit count towards the Unit matching (because you said Cost_1 doesn't count for that unit)?

Comment: ProfitTypes can have ProfitTypes, CostTypes, Units.
CostTypes can have CostTypes, Units.
Unit cannot have children.

The Profit does not count towards the Unit because Unit is not an immediate parent of Profit, but of Cost_2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't giving exactly the answers you provided as example, but see my comment above - if (null,222,8) should be 7 to match how (null,333,8) returns 4 then this is correct.

Also note that I formatted this using temp tables instead of as a function, I don't want to trip a schema change audit so I posted what I have as temp tables, I can rewrite it as a function Monday when my DBA is available, but I thought you might need it before the weekend. Just edit the "DECLARE @ProfitType int = ..." lines to the values you want to test

I also put in quite a few comments because the logic is tricky, but if they aren't enough leave a comment and I can expand my explanation

```
/*
ASSUMPTIONS: 
A tree can be of arbitrary depth, but will not exceed the recursion limit (defaults to 100)
All trees will include at least 1 CostType
All trees will have at most 1 ProfitType
CostType can appear multiple times in a traversal from root to leaf (can units?)
*/

SELECT *
INTO #Temp 
FROM (VALUES (1,'Root',NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
    , (2,'1', 1, 300, NULL, NULL)
    , (3,'1-1', 2, NULL, 111, NULL)
    , (4,'1-1-1', 3, NULL, NULL, 8)
    , (5,'1-2', 2, NULL, 222, NULL)
    , (6,'1-2-1', 5, NULL, 333, NULL)
    , (7,'1-2-1-1', 6, NULL, NULL, 8)
    , (8,'1-2-1-2', 6, NULL, NULL, 9)
    ) as TempTable(ID, RName, Parent_ID, ProfitType, CostType, UnitID)

--SELECT * FROM #Temp
DECLARE @ProfitType int = NULL--300
DECLARE @CostType INT = 333 --NULL --111
DECLARE @UnitID INT = NULL--8
--SELECT * FROM #Temp

;WITH cteMatches as (
    --Start with all nodes that match one criteria, default a score of 100
    SELECT N.ID as ReportID, *, 100 as Score, 1 as Depth 
    FROM #Temp AS N
    WHERE N.CostType= @CostType OR N.ProfitType=@ProfitType OR N.UnitID = @UnitID 
), cteEval as (
    --This is a recursive CTE, it has a (default) limit of 100 recursions
    --, but that can be raised if your trees are deeper than 100 nodes
    --Start with the base case
    SELECT M.ReportID, M.RName, M.ID ,M.Parent_ID, M.Score 
        , M.Depth, M.ProfitType , M.CostType , M.UnitID 
    FROM cteMatches as M 
    UNION ALL 
    --This is the recursive part, add to the list of matches the match when 
    --its immediate parent is also considered. For that match increase the score
    --if the parent contributes another match. Also update the ID of the match 
    --to the parent's IDs so recursion can keep adding if more matches are found
    SELECT M.ReportID, M.RName, N.ID ,N.Parent_ID
        , M.Score + CASE WHEN N.CostType= @CostType 
            OR N.ProfitType=@ProfitType 
            OR N.UnitID = @UnitID THEN 100 ELSE 0 END as Score
    , M.Depth + 1, N.ProfitType , N.CostType , N.UnitID 
    FROM cteEval as M INNER JOIN #Temp AS N on M.Parent_ID = N.ID 
)SELECT TOP 1 * --Drop the "TOP 1 *" to see debugging info (runners up)
FROM cteEval
ORDER BY SCORE DESC, DEPTH

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Comment: The recursiveness here gave me an idea on how to do this. Will experiment with it today and get back. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I don't have enough rep to comment.

You'll have to define "best answer" (for example, why isn't the answer to null,222,8 7 or null instead of 5?), but here's the approach I'd use:

Derive a new table where ProfitType and CostType are listed explicitly instead of only by inheritance.  I would approach that by using a cursor (how awful, I know) and following the parent_id until a ProfitType and CostType is found -- or the root is reached.  This presumes an unlimited amount of child/grandchild levels for parent_id.  If there is a limit, then you can instead use N self joins where N is the number of parent_id levels allowed.

Then you run multiple queries against the derived table.  The first query would be for an exact match (and then exit if found).  Then next query would be for the "best" partial match (then exit if found), followed by queries for 2nd best, 3rd best, etc. until you've exhausted your "best" match criteria.

If you need nested parent CostTypes to be part of the "best match" criteria, then I would make duplicate entries in the derived table for each row that has multiple CostTypes with a CostType "level".  level 1 is the actual CostType. level 2 is that CostType's parent, level 3 etc.  Then your best match queries would return multiple rows and you'd need to pick the row with the lowest level (which is the closest parent/grandparent).